# Linq, how to group data by ID and merge data within that ID

Tags: c#, linq

From the database I get the following values

```
PlanningID = GetValue<int>(dataReader["PlanningID"]),
PlanningStatus = GetValue<string>(dataReader["PlanningStatus"]),
Private = GetValue<int>(dataReader["Private"])
Social = GetValue<int>(dataReader["Social"])
```

PlanningID, PlanningStatus, Private

- 1,          good,          10
- 1,          fair,           5
- 1,           bad,           1

I want to group these by `planningID` so that it looks like this

```
public class ClassResult
{
   public int planningID { get; set; }
   public List<PlanningStatus> PlanningStatus { get; set; }
}

public class PlanningStatus
{
   public string PlanningStatus { get; set; }
   public int Private { get; set; }
   public int Social{ get; set; }
}
```

I tried this but the output was wrong:

```
IEnumerable<ClassResult> classResult =
                from result in results
                group result by new
                {
                    result.PlanningID,
                    result.PlanningStatus
                } into grouping

                select new ClassResult
                {
                    PlanningID = grouping.Key.PlanningID,
                    PlanningStatus = grouping.Key.PlanningStatus,                    
                    Private = grouping.First().Private,
                    Social = grouping.First().Social
                };

return lrrResults;
```

To be honest I got no idea how to do this

**Updated projection as advised below but still have multiple planning id's of lets say 1**

```
            var results =
            from result in results
            group result by result.PlanningID
            into grouping
            select new ClassResult
            {
                PlanningID = grouping.Key,                     
                PlanningStatusType = grouping.Select(item => new PlanningStatusType
                {
                    PlanningStatus = item.PlanningStatus,
                    Private = item.Private,
                    Social = item.Social,
                }).ToList(),
                LatestChange = grouping.First().LatestChange,
                WeeklyChangeType = grouping.First().WeeklyChangeType,
                Address = grouping.First().Address
            };
```

Comment: Please edit the question to also explain what is wrong with the input you received - it will make this question more helpful in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query above you are grouping by both the `PlanningID` and `PlanningStatus` so the groups will contain 1 item each. What you want to do is as following:

1. Instantiate a new `ClassResult` as you did but setting the `planningID` but the `.Key` (which is now just a single property
2. Project each item of the grouping to a new object of type `PlanningStatus` using the `.Select()`

Code:

```
var classResult = from result in results
                  group result by result.PlanningID into grouping
                  select new ClassResult
                  {
                      PlanningID = grouping.Key,
                      PlanningStatus = grouping.Select(item => new PlanningStatus {
                          PlanningStatus = item.PlanningStatus,
                          Private = item.Private,
                          Social = item.Social
                      }).ToList()
                  };
```

Tested on some sample code and works:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your way makes sense but it still doesn't merge the planningid's. I've added your code to the question

Comment: @insanepaul - please check your data carefully because when testing it on sample data like you show in your question it does group properly. See update

Comment: Thanks again for responding. I did what you did which grouped properly. I then looked at my data in more detail but because of the complexity of the data I was grabbing the wrong ID!!! So now it works which is great news as I can now move onto the next stage. Thanks again